# Git-Bash, "error kex-exchange_identification"

Tags: git, github, ssh

The command "git pull upstream main" causes the following error <kex_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort
banner exchange: Connection to "IP.adress" port 22: Software caused connection abort
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.>

The repository exists. Hence I do not know how to solve it as I am new to github. Do you know a solution or a possible reason for the error?

Comment: Can you post the output of `ssh git@github.com -vT` command

Comment: "Software caused connection abort" means "they refuse to talk to you". Typically this is because GitHub is down (this is rare but does happen sometimes) or, more commonly, because you have some kind of network spy/filter box (or program) between you and GitHub and *that* box has turned off your access to GitHub. If it's the latter, the trick is to figure out where that box is and how to change its setup.

Comment: If you can't fix whatever's wrong here, there are two alternatives: you can try to contact GitHub on a different port (they accept ssh requests on the https port, which is usually not *blocked* although these filtering boxes tend to damage the network traffic on those ports), or, you can use https instead of ssh to contact GitHub (but again, see "filtering box may damage your data").